# LaTeX: optional arguments with square brackets

Tags: brackets, optional-arguments

LaTeX is trying to add a missing $ that I don't want to the following code. Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[letter,12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\monkeyBeans}[2][]{
  \parbox{4in}{#1}
}

\begin{document}

\parbox{4in}{$[a, b]$} 

\monkeyBeans[$[a, b]$]{yo monkey}

\end{document}
```

If I try any of the following lines in my document instead of the call to monkeyBeans, there is no error:

```
\parbox{4in}{$[a, b]$} 
\monkeyBeans[yo monkey]{$[a, b]$}
\monkeyBeans[$(a, b)$]{yo monkey}
\monkeyBeans{$[a, b]$}{yo monkey}
```

What is the deal with square brackets in optional arguments?

Comment: Where is the rest of the `tabular` that is ended in `\monkeyBeans`? A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) would really help here. It should start with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You will need to enclose an optional argument with square brackets in braces (i.e. `\monkeyBeans[{$[a, b]$}]{yo monkey}` or `[${[a, b]}$]`, …) otherwise the inner/first `]` is used as the end of your optional argument, and then all hell breaks loose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bug? LaTeX misparses nested optional arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78414/bug-latex-misparses-nested-optional-arguments)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*Note: Without a MWE I will remove `\end{tabular}` from the definition of your macro and ignore the fact that you declare two argments (one optional, one mandatory) but use only `#1`.*

An optional argument behaves quite different from normal arguments and groups as it is catched by TeX with the help of the `[`/`]` delimiters.

With a macro is defined with

```
\newcommand{\monkeyBeans}[2][]{\parbox{4in}{#1}}
```

and called with

```
\monkeyBeans[$[a, b]$]{yo monkey}
```

`#1` will be `$[a, b`. `#2` will be `$` and in this case discarded as `#2` is not used in your macro definition. Therefore, `\monkeyBeans[$[a, b]$]{yo monkey}` is expanded to

```
\parbox{4in}{$[a, b}]{yo monkey}
```

No wonder there's a `$` missing! I'd miss it, too.

With a macro `\monkeyBean` defined as

```
\newcommand{\monkeyBean}[1][]{\parbox{4in}{#1}}
```

and used with

```
\monkeyBean[$[a, b]$]yo monkey
```

It's even clearer what happens, as TeX complies twice about an missing `$` because that line expands to

```
\parbox{4in}{$[a, b}$]yo monkey
```

and “]yo monkey” is typeset in math mode, too.

---

**Solution:** Enclose optional arguments with a `]` in braces, so that they get grouped:

```
\monkeyBean[{$[a, b]$}]
\monkeyBeans[{$[a, b]$}]{yo monkey}
```

Comment: Qrrbrbirlbel: Thank you, this was extremely informative and clear.  You even got around my copy-paste error in the original question!  It makes some sense, that LaTeX wouldn't notice the entering/exiting of math mode inside the square brackets.  I was a bit surprised that: \monkeyBeans[\([a, b]\)]{yo monkey} also causes the error.

Answer (score 6):

Qrrbrbirlbel's solution is the standard LaTeX2e approach, and is certainly what you have to do for an arbitrary command. The LaTeX3 package [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) deals with the nesting in a cleaner way:

```
\documentclass[letter,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\monkeyBeans}{O{}m}{%
  \parbox{4in}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\parbox{4in}{$[a, b]$} 

\monkeyBeans[$[a, b]$]{yo monkey}

\end{document}
```

which works of course only if you are defining the command where `[]` nesting is required.