# Scaling molecules on top of arrow with chemfig

Tags: chemfig

i've a problem with chemfig-package. I want to draw some mulecules above an `\arrow{-U>}`, but i can't scale them in the right way. Does anybody has an idea to work around or do I just made a mistake?

Here's some code for you:

```
\documentclass[draft=yes,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!tbp,width=\textwidth]
\schemedebug{true}
\schemestart
  \chemfig[][scale=.7]{*6((-O_{2}N)-=-(-([::-60]-H)([::+60]=O))=-=)}\arrow{0}[,0]\+\arrow{0}[,0]
  \chemfig[][scale=.7]{[:75]HO-(=[::+60]O)-[::-60]-[::-60](=[::+60]O)-[::-60]HO}
  \arrow{-U>[\chemfig{N*6(-=-=-=)}][\chemfig{N*6(-=-=-=)}]}
\schemestop
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As you see, the molecule does appear above the arrow, but it isn't scaleable with `[scale=.2]`, i.e.

Comment: As always when you want to use square brackets in an optional argument you have to enclose the argument in an extra pair of braces: `\arrow{-U>[{\chemfig[][scale=.5]{N*6(-=-=-=)}}][{\chemfig[][scale=.5]{N*6(-=-=-=)}}]}[,2]`

Comment: The extra pair of braces did it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: related: [LaTeX: optional arguments with square brackets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84595/latex-optional-arguments-with-square-brackets), http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99495/inside-an-optional-argument, [Bug? LaTeX misparses nested optional arguments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78414/bug-latex-misparses-nested-optional-arguments) and possibly more... the most complete answer being http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99514/5049

Answer (score 1):

Turning my comment into an answer (just to remove this question from the unanswered ones):

As always when you want to use square brackets in an optional argument you have to enclose the argument in an extra pair of braces. There are quite a number of questions related to this fact:

- [LaTeX: optional arguments with square brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84595/latex-optional-arguments-with-square-brackets)
- [] inside an optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99495/inside-an-optional-argument)
- [Bug? LaTeX misparses nested optional arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78414/bug-latex-misparses-nested-optional-arguments)

probably the most complete answer being the one by [Frank Mittelbach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10109/frank-mittelbach) to the [second of the linked questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99514/5049).

Let's see that it works:

```
\documentclass[draft=yes,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!tbp,width=\textwidth]
\schemedebug{true}
\schemestart
  \chemfig[][scale=.7]{*6((-O_{2}N)-=-(-([::-60]-H)([::+60]=O))=-=)}\arrow{0}[,0]\+\arrow{0}[,0]
  \chemfig[][scale=.7]{[:75]HO-(=[::+60]O)-[::-60]-[::-60](=[::+60]O)-[::-60]HO}
  \arrow{-U>[{\chemfig[][scale=.4]{N*6(-=-=-=)}}][{\chemfig[][scale=.4]{N*6(-=-=-=)}}]}
\schemestop
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]