# Using square bracket inside square bracket

Tags: brackets

I have a two-column layout, and I want to put a specific section with images to span the whole page width. So I use:

```
\twocolumn[
...
]
```

So far, so good. However, when I want to include anything in this block that also includes a square bracket `]`, then this fails (variety of errors depending on what goes on inside the brackets). How should I go around this?

Example error:

```
\twocolumn[
  \includegraphics[width=15cm]{abc.jpg}
]
```

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84595/latex-optional-arguments-with-square-brackets, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99495/inside-an-optional-argument, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78414/bug-latex-misparses-nested-optional-arguments and possibly more... the most complete answer being http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99514/5049

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\twocolumn[
 {\includegraphics[width=15cm]{abc.jpg}}
]
```

(Grouping {} added).