# Scaling a graphics leads to an error

Tags: graphics

I have the following problem: I want to attach a photo in my resume on the right top. If I not use a scale argument, the file compiles but the photo is to large. However using a scale argument leads to an error:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% NOTE: If you find that it says                                     %%
%%                                                                    %%
%%                           1 of ??                                  %%
%%                                                                    %%
%% at the bottom of your first page, this means that the AUX file     %%
%% was not available when you ran LaTeX on this source. Simply RERUN  %%
%% LaTeX to get the ``??'' replaced with the number of the last page  %%
%% of the document. The AUX file will be generated on the first run   %%
%% of LaTeX and used on the second run to fill in all of the          %%
%% references.                                                        %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Document Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Don't like 10pt? Try 11pt or 12pt
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% This is a helpful package that puts math inside length specifications
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Simpler bibsection for CV sections
% (thanks to natbib for inspiration)
\makeatletter
\newlength{\bibhang}
\setlength{\bibhang}{1em}
\newlength{\bibsep}
 {\@listi \global\bibsep\itemsep \global\advance\bibsep by\parsep}
\newenvironment{bibsection}%
        {\begin{list}{}{%
       \setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
       \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
       \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibsep}%
       \setlength{\parsep}{\z@}%
        \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}}}
        {\end{list}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}
\makeatother

% Layout: Puts the section titles on left side of page
\reversemarginpar

%
%         PAPER SIZE, PAGE NUMBER, AND DOCUMENT LAYOUT NOTES:
%
% The next \usepackage line changes the layout for CV style section
% headings as marginal notes. It also sets up the paper size as either
% letter or A4. By default, letter was used. If A4 paper is desired,
% comment out the letterpaper lines and uncomment the a4paper lines.
%
% As you can see, the margin widths and section title widths can be
% easily adjusted.
%
% ALSO: Notice that the includefoot option can be commented OUT in order
% to put the PAGE NUMBER *IN* the bottom margin. This will make the
% effective text area larger.
%
% IF YOU WISH TO REMOVE THE ``of LASTPAGE'' next to each page number,
% see the note about the +LP and -LP lines below. Comment out the +LP
% and uncomment the -LP.
%
% IF YOU WISH TO REMOVE PAGE NUMBERS, be sure that the includefoot line
% is uncommented and ALSO uncomment the \pagestyle{empty} a few lines
% below.
%

%% Use these lines for letter-sized paper
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,
            %includefoot, % Uncomment to put page number above margin
            marginparwidth=1.2in,     % Length of section titles
            marginparsep=.05in,       % Space between titles and text
            margin=1in,               % 1 inch margins
            includemp]{geometry}

%% Use these lines for A4-sized paper
%\usepackage[paper=a4paper,
%            %includefoot, % Uncomment to put page number above margin
%            marginparwidth=30.5mm,    % Length of section titles
%            marginparsep=1.5mm,       % Space between titles and text
%            margin=25mm,              % 25mm margins
%            includemp]{geometry}

%% More layout: Get rid of indenting throughout entire document
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

%% Reference the last page in the page number
%
% NOTE: comment the +LP line and uncomment the -LP line to have page
%       numbers without the ``of ##'' last page reference)
%
% NOTE: uncomment the \pagestyle{empty} line to get rid of all page
%       numbers (make sure includefoot is commented out above)
%
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\pagestyle{empty}      % Uncomment this to get rid of page numbers
\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfootoffset{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\newlength{\footpageshift}
\setlength{\footpageshift}
          {0.5\textwidth+0.5\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth-2in}
\lfoot{\hspace{\footpageshift}%
       \parbox{4in}{\, \hfill %
                    \arabic{page} of \protect\pageref*{LastPage} % +LP
%                    \arabic{page}                               % -LP
                    \hfill \,}}

% Finally, give us PDF bookmarks
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor = black, citecolor = black, filecolor = black, urlcolor = blue]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{color,hyperref}
%\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.3}
%\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,
%            linkcolor=darkblue,urlcolor=darkblue,
%            anchorcolor=darkblue,citecolor=darkblue}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% End Document Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Helper Commands %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% The title (name) with a horizontal rule under it
% (optional argument typesets an object right-justified across from name
%  as well)
%
% Usage: \makeheading{name}
%        OR
%        \makeheading[right_object]{name}
%
% Place at top of document. It should be the first thing.
% If ``right_object'' is provided in the square-braced optional
% argument, it will be right justified on the same line as ``name'' at
% the top of the CV. For example:
%
%       \makeheading[\emph{Curriculum vitae}]{Your Name}
%
% will put an emphasized ``Curriculum vitae'' at the top of the document
% as a title. Likewise, a picture could be included:
%
%   \makeheading[\includegraphics[height=1.5in]{my_picutre}]{Your Name}
%
% the picture will be flush right across from the name.
\newcommand{\makeheading}[2][]%
        {\hspace*{-\marginparsep minus \marginparwidth}%
         \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}%
             {\large \bfseries #2 \hfill #1}\\[-0.15\baselineskip]%
                 \rule{\columnwidth}{1pt}%
         \end{minipage}}

% The section headings
%
% Usage: \section{section name}
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\pagebreak[3]%
    \hyphenpenalty=10000%
    \vspace{1.3\baselineskip}%
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
    \noindent\llap{\scshape\smash{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedright #1}}}%
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}\par}

% An itemize-style list with lots of space between items
\newenvironment{outerlist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\begin{itemize}[#1,leftmargin=*]}{\end{itemize}%
         \vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}

% An environment IDENTICAL to outerlist that has better pre-list spacing
% when used as the first thing in a \section
\newenvironment{lonelist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\begin{list}{#1}{%
        \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}}}
        {\end{list}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}

% An itemize-style list with little space between items
\newenvironment{innerlist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\begin{itemize}[#1,leftmargin=*,parsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]}
        {\end{itemize}}

% An environment IDENTICAL to innerlist that has better pre-list spacing
% when used as the first thing in a \section
\newenvironment{loneinnerlist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\begin{itemize}[#1,leftmargin=*,parsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]}
        {\end{itemize}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}

% To add some paragraph space between lines.
% This also tells LaTeX to preferably break a page on one of these gaps
% if there is a needed pagebreak nearby.
\newcommand{\blankline}{\quad\pagebreak[3]}
\newcommand{\halfblankline}{\quad\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}\pagebreak[3]}

% Uses hyperref to link DOI
\newcommand\doilink[1]{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{#1}}
\newcommand\doi[1]{doi:\doilink{#1}}

% For \url{SOME_URL}, links SOME_URL to the url SOME_URL
\providecommand*\url[1]{\href{#1}{#1}}
% Same as above, but pretty-prints SOME_URL in teletype fixed-width font
\renewcommand*\url[1]{\href{#1}{\texttt{#1}}}

% For \email{ADDRESS}, links ADDRESS to the url mailto:ADDRESS
\providecommand*\email[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{#1}}
% Same as above, but pretty-prints ADDRESS in teletype fixed-width font
%\renewcommand*\email[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{\texttt{#1}}}

%\providecommand\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
%    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
%\providecommand\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
%    \TeX}}
\providecommand\BibTeX{{B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    \TeX}}
\providecommand\Matlab{\textsc{Matlab}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% End Helper Commands %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Begin CV Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\makeheading[\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{pic.jpg}]{My full name}

\section{\textbf{Hi HO}}

% NOTE: Mind where the & separators and \\ breaks are in the following
%       table.
%
% ALSO: \rcollength is the width of the right column of the table
%       (adjust it to your liking; default is 1.85in).
%
\newlength{\rcollength}\setlength{\rcollength}{2.5in}%
%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\textwidth-\rcollength}p{\rcollength}}

Randomstr. 21           & \textit{Mobile:} A funny phone number \\
87129 Apple Pie           & \textit{Home:} A funny home number \\
Moon                & \textit{E-mail:} \email{myname@whatever.com}                           
\end{tabular}

\section{\textbf{I want!!!!!!}}  A position within your firm as a wizard.


\section{\textbf{hello}} {\sl Birthday:} Sorry, I'm to old\\
                            {\sl Born:} Mordor



\section{\textbf{Yeah! done!}} {\sl 2012-2014:} MSc in reading Harry Potter books \\
{\sl University:} Hogwards, \href{http://www.google.com}{hogwards}
 \begin{itemize}
\item Major: Quiditch, \href{http://www.google.com}{lilalu}
\item Master-Thesis: "Another never ending love story"
\end{itemize}
                % \sl will be bold italic in New Century Schoolbook (or
            % any postscript font) and just slanted in
        % Computer Modern (default) font
{\sl 2008-2012:} BSc in playing guitarre\\ 
{\sl University:} University of Rock, \href{http://www.google.com}{Rock n Roll}
\begin{itemize}
\item Bachelor-Thesis: ``Never ending love story''
\end{itemize}
\section{\textbf{some questions?}} {\sl What?:} horse \\
                    {\sl Where:} sea\\
                    {\sl why:} boring     
\section{\textbf{more}} 
                       {\sl Who:} Prince \\
                       {\sl really:}
                       \begin{itemize}
                 \item yes
                 \item no
                 \item maybe
                 \item ok
                \end{itemize}



\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% End CV Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
% The following is copyright and licensing information for
% redistribution of this LaTeX source code; it also includes a liability
% statement. If this source code is not being redistributed to others,
% it may be omitted. It has no effect on the function of the above code.
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
% Copyright (c) 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011 by Theodore P. Pavlic
%
% Unless otherwise expressly stated, this work is licensed under the
% Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial 3.0 United States License. To
% view a copy of this license, visit
% http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/us/ or send a letter to
% Creative Commons, 171 Second Street, Suite 300, San Francisco,
% California, 94105, USA.
%
% THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS
% OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
% MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
% IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
% CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
% TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
% SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
```

So using once the code `\makeheading[\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{pic.jpg}]{My full name}` produces an error, however using `\makeheading[\includegraphics{pic.jpg}]{My full name}` it compiles but the picture is to large. I added a picture below. Note, I also tried to use `width=/length=` producing the same error. How can I use the scale function properly? Just for completeness here is the error message:

```
! Argument of \Gin@ii has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.220 ...\makeheading[\includegraphics[width=3cm]p
                                                  ic.jpg}]{My full name}
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
width=3cm
! Paragraph ended before \Gin@ii was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.220 ...\makeheading[\includegraphics[width=3cm]p
                                                  ic.jpg}]{My full name}
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.


! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.220 ...\makeheading[\includegraphics[width=3cm]p
                                                  ic.jpg}]{My full name}
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

! Too many }'s.
l.220 ...ading[\includegraphics[width=3cm]pic.jpg}
                                                  ]{My full name}
You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.


Overfull \hbox (40.83345pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 220--221
[]| []\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ic.jpg]My
 []


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/bx/n' instead on input line 222.

\rcollength=\skip60
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 232.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 232.

Overfull \hbox (18.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 232--238
[][] 
 []

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+cmr on input line 250.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd
File: omscmr.fd 1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OMS/cmr/m/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' tried instead on input line 250.

AED: lastpage setting LastPage [1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 276.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 276.
 (./test.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 276.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 276.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `test.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: BCA175A70C2E86A6152D11F00EBA3623;268.


LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 276.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 6273 strings out of 495031
 91835 string characters out of 6181530
 182597 words of memory out of 5000000
 9418 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 5553 words of font info for 20 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 29i,13n,43p,223b,322s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></us
r/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/shar
e/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texli
ve/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsl10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/tex
mf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dis
t/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 72354 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 68 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 58 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 8 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 49 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try with `\includegraphics[width=3cm]{pic.jpg}`? The length is just for testing.

Comment: @egreg I also tested that one, same error. I will include this in my question

Comment: If the graphic file doesn't scale, then it bears incorrect information. Are you compiling with `pdflatex`?

Comment: What's the actual error message? How big is the image (for example, if you view the image properties in an image viewer how many pixels wide and tall does it say)?

Comment: @egreg yess I'm using pdflatex

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I added the error message. The picture has exactly the same properties as the black one I included.

Comment: It's a known problem: you need `\makeheading[{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{pic.jpg}}]{My...}`

Comment: According to your error message, the problem is a missing brace. You had `\includegraphics[width=3cm]pic.jpg}` instead of `\includegraphics[width=3cm]{pic.jpg}`.

Comment: And of course the required extra braces that @egreg pointed out.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84595/latex-optional-arguments-with-square-brackets or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78414/bug-latex-misparses-nested-optional-arguments

Comment: @egreg thanks, that solved my problem!