# Cite in theorem header and giving the theorem a name

Tags: citing

I'd like to create a named theorem and cite it in the header like this:

Theorem 5.3 [1, Theorem 1.1][NAME]

I haven't seen a book where an author used that style, but I'd like to use that kind of reference for my thesis. (Or is there a better way to do that?)

What I tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cite}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{Literatur3.bib}
@book{GEOR,
Author = {Hans-Otto Georgii},
Publisher = {de Gruyter},
Title = {Stochastik},
Year = {2009}}

\end{filecontents*}
\bibliography{Literatur3.bib}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[{\cite[6.30]{GEOR}}][Name]
    ...
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

but that produces an error "Argument of @citex has an extra }. \begin{Theorem}[\cite[6.30]"

Is there a right way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use optional arguments inside an optional argument, you have to use additional argument braces for the outer optional argument: `\begin{Theorem}[{\cite[6.30]{bibitem}}](Name)`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84595/latex-optional-arguments-with-square-brackets

Comment: When I try that it produces
Theorem 2.2 ([1, 6.30]).   (Name)  

 with multiple spaces after the dot and (Name) is printed in italics

Comment: The result of `\cite` depends on the style you are using for cites and bibliography (I hope, you are using `biblatex`). The style of the theorem depends on the theorem packages and definitions you are using. Please make a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). And describe in detail, what you want. We cannot help you without these things.

Comment: I am pretty new to all this so please excuse my lack of knowledge. I used BibDesk which produces a .bib file. So is that biblatex in the end? MEW added to the Question

Comment: you're using `amsthm`.  there's an example similar to what i think you want on p.4 of the documentation; take a look: `texdoc amsthm'.  (but i don't know whether `scrartcl` makes and relevant modifications.  i'm also not sure of the effect of the `cite` package.)

Comment: Thank you so much! This looks not exactly as i imagined but that is still totally fine!

Comment: This is not a *working* example. Please have a look at: [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not produce a bibliography. If I fix this, either using:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cite}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{Literatur3.bib}
@book{GEOR,
Author = {Hans-Otto Georgii},
Publisher = {de Gruyter},
Title = {Stochastik},
Year = {2009}}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[{\cite[6.30]{GEOR}}][Name]
  ...
\end{theorem}

\bibliographystyle{plain}% the old bibtex way
\bibliography{Literatur3.bib}% the old bibtex way

\end{document}
```

or (I would recommend this):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{Literatur3.bib}
@book{GEOR,
Author = {Hans-Otto Georgii},
Publisher = {de Gruyter},
Title = {Stochastik},
Year = {2009}}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Literatur3.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[{\cite[6.30]{GEOR}}][Name]
  ...
\end{theorem}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I get not error message. The last example produces:

[image]