# How to escape [ and ]

Tags: captions, subfloats

Consider this script

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \subfloat[$a>5$~[a.u.]]{%                                                                                                                                                                                 
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}%                                                                                                                                                
  }
  \subfloat[$a\le5$~[a.u.]]{%                                                                                                                                                                               
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}%                                                                                                                                                
    }
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

`[]` inside `[]` is causing a distortion in the portrayal of the captions of the subfloats:

[image]

What is the best way to escape `[` and `]`?

Comment: A FAQ: `\subfloat[{$a>5$~[a.u.]}]{...}`

Comment: See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84595/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99495/35864

Comment: @moewe -- Excellent finds.  i juat added them to the [Often referenced questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419).  Please consider doing that next time you find a "FAQ" answer.

Comment: Will anybody provide an answer?