# Missing \item problem with enumerate

Tags: lists, enumerate

I get an error when trying to build my PDF in Texmaker, I have following lines of code giving me an issue despite working this morning:

```
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
\item Some text
\item Some text
\item Some text \\
\end{enumerate}
```

I get the following message:

[image]

As there are many issues that are similar I've tried the answer on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49882/yet-another-perhaps-a-missing-item-error) to see if my enumerate was bugging due to the `\\` and it wasn't the case. The strange thing is when I type the following it works perfectly:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Some text
\item Some text
\item Some text \\
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Does the problem appear if you completely remove the linebreak? And why do you have to use it anyway : the environment should correctly break the last line when it exits?

Comment: Interesting choice for the log's font …

Comment: @T.Verron If I remove the linebreak the problem persists and I had to add a linebreak otherwise the text I start typing afterwards starts aligned with the enumerate list rather than the edge of the page.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yeah I changed it while checking out fonts yesterday and haven't changed it back, although not the clearest of fonts, agreed:D

Comment: @Oyibo: You should consider using [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem).  With `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}` you can use the old style label, but I think it is better to switch to the new more explicit style: `[label={a)}]`

Comment: @PeterGrill thanks for the advice, its indeed more explicit!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a fix for this, I'd copied pasted all the `\usepackage` lines from another previous version of my document which didn't have `\usepackage{enumerate}`, once I added this package my document compiled perfectly as shown below:
[image]

I decided I'd leave the question open and post a solution anyways as it's easy to miss and took me quite a while to figure it out despite being an easy thing to fix.

Comment: Did you try adding/removing `\usepackage` lines on the new working document (towards the old one), until you see the bug appear?

Comment: I tried removing them one by one by putting them into comments to see which package I'd imported could be causing the issue, then once I'd gotten to the bottom of the list I realised that I'd not seen the enumerate one, was kind of lucky as I was in the process of posting the question here for help.

Comment: So basically you just removed `enumerate` from your included package? This is weird, because your code shouldn't compile in that case.

Comment: You've misunderstood what I wrote, I added `enumerate` and it worked, I had badly copy pasted the whole thing so it was missing and giving me the error.

Comment: Oooh... I thought you were waiting for a more proper solution. I guess you should accept your own answer, so that people know there is a solution on this page.

Comment: No worries, also you have to wait 48 hours after posting to accept your own answer, that's why I haven't accepted yet.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you should delete the `\` before `\end` and add `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}` to your tex document. An example from [TeXblog](http://texblog.net/latex-beginners-guide/examples/chapter-4/#enumerate)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
\item Some text
\item Some text
\item Some text
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textcircled{\scriptsize\Alph*},font=\sffamily]
  \item State the paper size by an option to the document class
  \item Determine the margin dimensions using one of these packages:
  \begin{itemize}[label=---,itemsep=-2pt]
    \item geometry
    \item typearea
  \end{itemize}
  \item Customize header and footer by one of these packages:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item fancyhdr
    \item scrpage2
  \end{itemize}
  \item Adjust the line spacing for the whole document
  \begin{itemize}
    \item by using the setspace package
    \item or by the command \verb|\linespread{factor}|
  \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: OutputFigure]

Comment: This (a) does not answer the question and (b) does not produce the posted image.

Comment: Thx, I have correct the code and image.

Comment: OK - but it still doesn't answer tho OPs question.

Comment: T^T I think I am answering the question...

Comment: From the OP's answer, it is the `enumerate` package that is being used and had been lost from the preamble.  Once reinstated the code worked fine.

Comment: Judging by the text in the post, that single backslash was likely a double backslash followed by a linebreak, but: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7168/double-backslashes-disappear-from-code